# Output of the program realloc(0,0);

Tags: c, realloc

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
 int* p=(int*)realloc(0,0);
printf("%d\n",((int*)p)[-1]);
}
```

*Output:17*

**What is the reason for the output?**

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. What did *you* expect to happen instead?

Comment: To get an answer, look at assembly code. This is invalid in C, it makes no sense to think about it looking at C code. Compiler produces some assembly from this C with undefined behavior. That assembly code is defined, so you can sensibly examine it. Note that re-compile with different compiler or optimizations may change the assembly code, so you need to re-do the analysis.

Answer (score 1):

[What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486)

- It's undefined behavior to de-reference the pointer returned from `realloc(0,0)`.
- It's undefined behavior to access any array out of bounds at index -1.

Anything could happen. Any result could be printed, including nothing at all, or a program crash.

All memory allocation functions follows this rule (C17 7.22.3) emphasis mine:

> If the size of
> the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation-defined: **either a null pointer
> is returned, or** the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that **the
> returned pointer shall not be used to access an object**.

Comment: The C90 standard requested that size 0 allocation returns NULL. This is undefined behavior since C99.

If non-NULL pointer is returned, and index of -1 is accessed: if standard C library is implemented in such a way that chain of allocation blocks is stored as a header before allocation data - it might be a value from that header. If not - it is typically just a random value from memory which precedes the allocated block; either last value from another allocated block, or a value from unallocated area.

Comment: Such access can also result in CPU generating page fault and the OS making it into unrecoverable segmentation fault, if the platform has the memory virtualized (like modern all modern CPUs).

Comment: @mefistotelis As per C tag wiki usage guidance, questions about C are assumed to be about the currently active ISO standard unless explicitly specified otherwise. And yes, C90 has many strange quirks that nobody can explain the rationale for. Ignoring out of bounds UB, where is "an unique pointer minus 1" pointing anyway? Surely not at the heap or it wouldn't be an unique pointer, now would it... because even C90 allowed to point at item `&array[size]`.

Comment: Pointers are implemented as memory addresses valid within address space of a process. So if ptr points at heap location, then (ptr - 1) will point at heap location as well. How it maps into the ISO std: The requirement of uniqueness is not broken, exactly because of UB. We cannot make any assumptions from values (including addresses) achieved through undefined behavior.

Comment: @mefistotelis "Pointers are implemented as memory addresses valid within address space of a process." As far as C pointer arithmetic is concerned, they are implemented as memory addresses valid within the address space of _an array_. Where a plain object is considered an array of 1 item.